# How to install vega-lite-cli

Tags: vega-lite

I would like to use vl2png, but I do not find a guide to install this cli.

I'm able to install vega gli via `npm install -g vega-cli`. How to do the same for vega-lite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `npm install -g vega-lite`

After I have the cli I need